# The file "manage.py" did not come with my GitHub sample code

Tags: python, django

I'm an old-school developer, learning Django and GitHub for the first time.  I'd like to study https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz, but when installed in my virtual environment, I can't find the file "manage.py".  A YouTube Django tutorial suggested I need to run "py manage.py runserver" to start a web server on my local machine.  (I was successful starting a server when following THAT tutorial, but I'm now studying source code from GitHub.)  There's clearly a difference in age between the sample project on GitHub and my YT tutorial...  Can someone please tell me if I'm going about the learning of Django correctly, and if I truly need manage.py to start a server?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an installable app, not a full project. As the instructions show, you should create your own project with `django-admin.py startproject`, then install this app and add it to the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Note, this looks like a pretty old library and may not be compatible with recent Django versions.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Drop the GitHub source into a folder living within *my* project, and use *my* manage.py to start a server...  That makes sense.  It sounds like you're also saying that subsequent releases of Django aren't necessarily backward compatible.  Does that mean that the GitHub project wasn't progressed?  And, as a solution, would I just locate an older version of Django to install?  Ultimately, I want to create a quiz/test site that will go live, but I need to get a handle on Bootstrap and Django.  Yikes!  Thanks!